# X11 Forwarding works on Windows with Xming and Putty, but not with ssh command line

Tags: ssh, putty, x11forwarding

I have a micro Amazon instance the I want to use for testing and everything is going fine until the title.  If I set up all the info in PuTTy, open it up and run 'xclock', all runs perfectly and it opens on Xming on my local desktop.  If, however, I run

```
ssh xxxxxxx.amazonaws.com xclock
```

I get

```
Error: Can't open display:
```

If I run either of

```
ssh xxxxxxx.amazonaws.com -X DISPLAY=localhost:0:0 xclock
ssh xxxxxxx.amazonaws.com -Y DISPLAY=localhost:0:0 xclock
```

I get the same again, but just after about a 30 second delay.

In .ssh/config in Windows, I do have

```
ForwardX11 yes
```

set, and I really can't think of anything more to get this working.  The fact that PuTTy is working perfectly, not no matter what I do on the command line, I get absolutely no joy is driving me crazy.

Can I even see the commands PuTTy is running somewhere, to see if it's doing some extra magic?

The ssh I'm running in Windows is MinGW32's.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried

```
ssh -X username@hostname xclock
```

Normally, the `DISPLAY` on the remote machine is *not* `0:0`, but will be set by `ssh` automatically.

Also, Putty has a command line mode too, all you have to do is to add it's directory to your path and you can do

```
plink -X username@hostname xclock
```

Comment: Also, use the -C flag to compress data on the connection. That might pick up the speed of the startup, and that might be part of PuTTy's "extra magic" (if any).